# R: combine two lists with same column names

Tags: r, list

I have two list elements:

List1[[1]] = {c(1,1,2), c(1,2,3), c(1,3,4)}

List2[[1]] = {c(2,1,5), c(2,2,6), c(2,3,7)}

I am trying to combine both the lists and produce another list:

List3[[1]] = {c(1,1,2), c(1,2,3), c(1,3,4), c(2,1,5), c(2,2,6), c(2,3,7)}

Can someone please help in how to combine these two lists into 1?

Both the lists have same column names, but different row values. The second column is recurring (as mentioned in the example!)

I have tried the `combine` function and `merge` function but they both are giving different results than expected.

Comment: `list` doesn't have column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `Map` where we concatenate (`c`) the corresponding `list` elements to a single one

```
Map(c, List1, List2)
```